# Standardize Color Range For Multiple Plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting multiple dataframes, where the color of the line is dependent on a variable in the dataframe. The problem is that for each plot, R makes the color spectrum relative to the range of each plot.

I would like for the range (and corresponding colors) to be kept constant for all of the dataframes I'm using. I won't know the range of numbers in advance, though they'll all be set before plotting. In addition, there will hundreds of values, so a manual mapping is not feasible.

As of right now, I have:

```
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- as.data.frame(list('x'=1:5,'y'=1:5,'colors'=6:10))
df2 <- as.data.frame(list('x'=1:5,'y'=1:5,'colors'=8:12))
qplot(data=df1,x,y,geom='line', colour=colors)
qplot(data=df2,x,y,geom='line', colour=colors)
```

The first plot produces:
[image]
where the color range goes from 6-10.

The second plot produces:
[image]
where the color range goes from 8-12

I would like a constant range for both that goes from 6-12.

Comment: `+ scale_color_gradient(limits = c(6, 12))`

Comment: Got it. Thank you!